# How to grab frame name with javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I grab the frame name from this string?

```
<iframe title="recaptcha challenge" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe?hl=en&amp;v=v1526338122299&amp;k=6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-&amp;cb=ylg7rbi4vs61#4u0yaht3nqk" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; outline: 1px solid blue;" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" name="4u0yaht3nqk" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This is what my current javascript code is:

```js
var str = '<iframe title="recaptcha challenge" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe?hl=en&amp;v=v1526338122299&amp;k=6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-&amp;cb=ylg7rbi4vs61#4u0yaht3nqk" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; outline: 1px solid blue;" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" name="4u0yaht3nqk" frameborder="0"></iframe>'; 
var res = str.match(/name=/);
console.log(res);
```

The final output should look like this:

```
4u0yaht3nqk
```

but my code doesn't work. Anyone can fix this? I need it to be regex only

Comment: You are hard coding the `str` with the `iframe` tag. Hardcode `res` with the name.

Comment: The reason you are doing this by string instead of the right way by DOM is because the `sandbox` is wide open and no site worth its salt would have anything to do with that gaping hole of exploit. In local it would work but Google blocks iframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the value of `name` using brackets in your regex:

```js
var str = '<iframe title="recaptcha challenge" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe?hl=en&amp;v=v1526338122299&amp;k=6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-&amp;cb=ylg7rbi4vs61#4u0yaht3nqk" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; outline: 1px solid blue;" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" name="4u0yaht3nqk" frameborder="0"></iframe>'; 
var res = str.match(/name="([^"]*)"/)
console.log(res != null ? res[1] : "not found");
```

Note this will fail if `name` contains an escaped quote mark.

Answer (score 0):

Just add what you want to catch and use result.

```js
var str = '<iframe title="recaptcha challenge" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe?hl=en&amp;v=v1526338122299&amp;k=6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-&amp;cb=ylg7rbi4vs61#4u0yaht3nqk" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; outline: 1px solid blue;" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" name="4u0yaht3nqk" frameborder="0"></iframe>'; 
var res = str.match(/name="(.+?)"/);//(.+?) contains captured value
console.log(res[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could turn the string into a proper DOM Node:

```
const element = document.createElement("template");
const str = '<iframe title="recaptcha challenge" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe?hl=en&amp;v=v1526338122299&amp;k=6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-&amp;cb=ylg7rbi4vs61#4u0yaht3nqk" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; outline: 1px solid blue;" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" name="4u0yaht3nqk" frameborder="0"></iframe>';

element.innerHTML = str;
const iframe = element.content.firstChild;
return iframe.name;
```

Note that you must use the `template` element to access your string as a DOM Node within `content.firstChild`.